# Devo usar SwingUtilities.invokeLater se não estender diretamente JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Olá. Eu percebo que as pessoas usam o método `invokeLater` de `SwingUtilities` quando estendem diretamente a classe `JFrame` e a inicializam no método `main`. Mas e se por acaso eu tiver um `JFrame` como atributo dentro de uma classe a qual não estende nenhuma outra classe, ainda devo utilizar esse método, não importando onde exatamente está declarado o `JFrame`, mas sim por ele estar presente no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## invokeLater

[Faz com que o runnable tenha seu método de execução chamado no encadeamento de despacho do sistema EventQueue. Isso acontecerá depois que todos os eventos pendentes forem processados.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

Outras explicações:
[aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Basicamente Swing usa Event dispatching thread. O metodo run vai ser chamado ao final do processo de todos os eventos da interface grafica.

Mas não precisa ser implementado só porque você tem um JFrame dentro da sua classe.

Comment: Acho que entendi melhor agora. O método faz uma coisa diferente do que eu imaginava. Obrigado pela resposta!